# How to register in a website using SMS

Tags: php, web, sms

I am developing a website and I want to add some feature like registration through SMS. Is there anyway I can do that, Please help me guys. A reply is very much Appreciated ! Thank you

Comment: show us your efforts.

Comment: You'll have to purchase an SMS device that can receive texts, then there is a simple command shell language to learn to manipulate it. Alternatively, there are services where you can pay per hundreds or thousands of texts and they own the machine.

Comment: Its a machine much like a cell phone. I believe there are even ways to use your actual cell phone to do this, but it would have to be tethered to the computer 24/7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take subscription of SMS gateway. There are many such SMS gateway. google it.
2. Create Short Code @ which users can SMS to register
3. Ask users to message in predefined SMS format.
4. Write a PHP script to connect with SMS gateway possible it will REST CALL or SOAP API.
5. Read SMS, Parse its content and register user as per detail in SMS
6. Write a CRON to execute above script.

Thanks

Comment: Fishing for easy points, eh? ;)

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply, thanks for the tips. I actually doesn't have an Idea in doing my work, So I'll take your Suggestions and I hope It will help me! God Bless